# Recognize a Matrix in a group of points

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a picture that I elaborate with my program to obtain a list of coordinates.

Represented in the image there is a matrix.
In an ideal test i would get only the sixteen central points of each square of the matrix.
But in actual tests i take pretty much noise points.

I want to use an algorithm to extrapolate from the list of the coordinates, the group formed by 16 coordinates that best represent a matrix.

The matrix can have any aspect ratio (beetween a range) and can result a little rotated.
But is always an 4x4 matrix.
The matrix is not always present in the image, but is not a problem, i need only the best matching.
Of course the founded point are always more than 16 (or i skip)

Example of founded points:

[image]

Example of desidered result:

[image]

If anyone can suggest me a preferred way to do this would be great.

Im thinking about the euclidean distance beetween points.

```
  For each point in the list:
     1. calculate the euclidean distance (D) with the others
     2. filter that points that D * 3 > image.widht (or height)
     3. see if it have at least 2 point at the same (more or less) distance,
        if not skip
     4. if yes put the point in a list and for each same-distance founded points: go to 2nd step.
```

at the end if i have 16 points in the list, this could be a matrix.

Any better suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: You want a shape with a periodic lattice ? Peridocity on X-line or Y-line or both? What about angular symetricity? You want diamond shapes too?

Comment: A Diamond shapes is never rappresented. I think the max rotation (starting with a perfect square) can be 45° (and -45°).
Yes, the shape have a periodic lattice (X and Y) but when i extrapolate the points form the image, the extrapolated points differs a little.

Comment: Wouldn't a square rotated 45° be a diamond shape?

Comment: @mbeckish I thought the exact same thing. :P Anyway, Euclidean distance seems useless. Use a 2d vector, that way you can actually see if the four points are in a line.

Comment: @mbeckish My mistake! So the answer is Yes, it can have a diamond shape :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the algorithm that springs to mind:

```
for each pair of points (p1, p2):
    let d be the distance vector (x and y) between them
    if d.x > (image.width-p1.x)/3 or d.y > (image.height-p1.y)/3:
        continue
    let d_t be d turned 90 degrees (d.y, -d.x)
    for i from 0 to 3:
        for j from 0 to 3:
            if there is no point at p1 + i*d + j*d_t:
                continue outer loop
    if you get here, you have a 4*4 grid
```

To cut the running time in half (on average), you could just consider the p2's that are to the right of p1.

Comment: With a little percentage threshold on the initial distance, the algorithm can be error tollerant finding the matrix points, changing the IF with:
`if the distance of nearest point at p1 + i*d + j*d_t differ more than the 4% with d`

Comment: Yeah, if the data is noisy or float-valued do that. Also my algo assumes the matrix will be square, so be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much processing power you want to use, and assuming a "little rotation" means very little, you could try the following:
1)taking just the X coordinates of the points, search for clusters of size 4.

2)For each cluster, look to see for each cluster to the left with distance d, if there are two more with distances 2*d and 3*d.

3)If yes, the compare the y coordinates for each of these clusters to see if they are roughly equal.

Depending on the data, you may get better performance doing step three before step two and using it to prune the options you consider.